# how to preserve activity state with multiple activities android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-screen

I have two `activities` A & B in my app.
I've learned how to save and restore all data whenever config change happens.
In my app, a user has to go to activity B from A (all the data is in B).

Now, whenever screen rotation happens, app restarts and goes to activity A.

How can I know about the last activity before screen rotation happened so that I can directly open the same activity and let my user continue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it might help you.

Paste this code second activity. **This method is called when screen orientation change.**

**For ex: portrait to landscape or vice versa.**

Take one variable and manipulate that variable value to know on previous activity.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   //Write Logic for start the same activity like and restore the data.
   startActivity(new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I am looking for a way to know the last activity before screen rotation happened. How do I know whether its activity A or B before screen rotation ?

Comment: @nani You want to open the previous activity when screen rotation change right??

Comment: yes. I want to know what activity user was working on.
if it was just activity A, no worries.
else if it was activity B, I want to open the same activity and restore all the data.

Comment: @nani you can use above code this method called when orientation change. You need to override this method in every activity. When screen orientation change then it open the same activity and restore the data.

Comment: I've implemented this method.
At first, I want to know if the user was in activity B and only then do redirect to that activity B. 
Otherwise, if the user was in activity A and did screen rotation, there's no need for me to redirect the user to activity B. 
I am sorry if this is confusing !!

Comment: so, How exactly I can know if the user was in activity B before screen rotation ?

Comment: Take a variable for this set true when open the activity B if screen orientation change. if you are on activity B you will found true in variable then start the B activity. this variable should be false for other activities.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23592/discussion-between-nani-and-tgmcians)